# How to use allauth in Django to send a email to users who sign up

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using allauth in my Django site to have users sign up. I want everyone who signs up to automatically receive an email that thanks them for signing up, etc.

I couldn't find a setting for this in the allauth configuration (http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html), but there must be a straight forward way to do this. Are there any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use signals from django [allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html)

```
allauth.account.signals.user_signed_up(request, user)
```